# Maclaurin expansion of zero

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have heard that there is a function $f(x)$ whose Maclaurin expansion is zero but f(x) is not identical to zero.

In other words, there exists a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $f^{(n)}(0)$ is zero for every whole number $n$ and $f(x)\neq0$.

Could you show me one of such functions? (I've heard it exists but I've never seen one)

Comment: See $C^\infty_c$, [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Examples) and $f(x) = e^{-1/x} 1_{x > 0}$

Comment: Doesn't $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, when $x\ne 0$, with $f(0)=0$ do it?

Comment: Yes, such an exponential function looks like working. I'm trying to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

If we take $f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$, then we have (for $x \neq 0$) $$f'(x) = \frac{P'(x)Q(x) - P(x)Q'(x)}{Q(x)^2}e^{-1/x^2} + \frac{2P(x)}{x^3Q(x)}e^{-1/x^2}$$
which assures us that $f'(x)$ will be of the same form (namely, a rational function times $e^{-1/x^2}$). Meanwhile, we know that $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{P(x)}{xQ(x)}e^{-1/x^2},$ but given that the exponential asymptotically dominates polynomials and that $e^{-1/x^2} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, we know that regardless of $xQ(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, we must have $f'(0) = 0.$

It follows by induction that $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ satisfies $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$. Thus $f(x)$ can't be computed by its Taylor series.

Comment: I would say if $f^{(n)}(0) =C \ne 0$ is the 1st non-zero derivative then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} = \frac{C}{n!}$.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure I follow you - are you suggesting $n$-fold application of L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: $f$ is $k$-times differentiable at $x=0$ iff $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n + o(x^n)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes you appear to be talking about *bump functions*.
Contrast the complex case, where differentiable  (holomorphic) implies (complex) analytic.   The bump function,  on the other hand, doesn't equal its Taylor series at O (MacLaurin series ), though it's smooth.   If it did it would be zero. ..